# Как узнать позицию угла геометрической фигуры?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, математика

Фигуру рисовать на канвасе нет необходимости, нужно только разместить блоки равномерно по углам многоугольника (5-ти, 6-ти, 7-ми и т.д.) как показано на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С пятиугольником не так все страшно, а вот дальше непонятно.
Какие могут быть решения?

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Чем 5-угольник существенно лучше 7-угольника? Почему вычисления для 5-угольника нельзя обобщить на n-угольник?

Comment: А можно обобщить? Формулы то разные! Диаметр естественно всегда известен.

Comment: Формула одна, вам нужен радиус и кол-во углов) из которых можно узнать положение угловой точки
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%F0%E0%E2%E8%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9_%EC%ED%EE%E3%EE%F3%E3%EE%EB%FC%ED%E8%EA

Comment: Как это разные? Одинаковые. Или у вас формула как-то существенно опирается на число 5? Приведите её.

Comment: Чуть неверно прочел условие, если вы имели ввиду произвольный многоугольник а не правильный там немного подругому будет) нужно знать так же длинну каждой стороны и вектор направленности, но судя из примера у вас таки случай с правильным многоугольником.

Comment: можно ли делать блоки с помощью css transform вокруг центра назначая угол поворота, потом както узнавать точку блока?

Comment: Как то так(не проверял)

    R = a/(2 x sin (360 / (2 x n))), где
    PosX=R*(COS(NS*(360/n-1)))
    PosY=R*(SIN(NS*(360/n-1)))
     Где
     a - сторона правильного многоугольника(длинна стороны);
     n - количество его сторон.
     NS- номер угла многоугольника.

Актуально для 4+ угольника.

Comment: Круто, это уже похоже на праду. А как нумеровать углы? С какого начинать?

Comment: Вопрос мертв?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас все N-угольники правильные( все стороны равны ), то величина каждого угла с вершиной в точке, являющейся центром вписанной в многоугольник окружности и со сторонами, проходящими через 2 соседние вершины будет равна **360/N** градусов . Следовательно, вы для начала будто бы рисуете окружность, затем высчитываете величину центрального угла (360/N) и далее находите координаты **X** и **Y** таким образом:

```
X = r*cos(A)
Y = r*sin(A)
```

где **r** - радиус той самой вписанной окружности, а **А**(альфа) - величина угла в градусах.

Ну, а далее, как говорится, дело техники :)

Comment: Я сначало не понял что за альфа!! Потом доперло что это внтрений углол. И что бы узнать позицию слеющего надо прибавлять угол предигущих. Спасибо

Comment: Да, именно так. Пожалуйста :)